# Not sure what's going on in my recursion (Read Access Violation)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> arr;

string duel(int s, int n) {
    int y, count = 0, i = 0;
    bool found = false;


    if (n == 1) {
        if (s > arr[0][0])
            return "YES";
        else return "NO";
    }
    else if (n > 1)
        while (!found && i < arr.size()) {
            if (s > arr[i][0]) {
                y = arr[i][1];
                arr.erase(arr.begin() + i);
                i++;
                count++;
                found = true;
                duel(s + y, n - 1);
            }
        }
    if (count == 0)
        return "NO";
}

int main()
{
    int s, n, x, y;

    cin >> s >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> x >> y;
        arr.push_back({ x, y });
    }

    cout << duel(s, n);
}
```

So I'm trying to solve this problem from codeforces https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/230/A. I'm using recursion, but I get the errors  "Read Access Violation" and "Error reading characters of string." I tried debugging myself and I noticed that when I add a return "NO" to the very end of the method, I don't get any errors, but all my answers become "NO", which is problematic.

If you run the first example in my code, which is

2 2

1 99

100 0

It starts off with duel(2, 2) with arr having the value of {{1, 99}, {100, 0}}. Then in duel, it deletes {1, 99} and leaves arr with only {100, 0}. Then it does duel(101, 1). I'm 100% sure in all of this, because I've printed out these values. However, why doesn't duel(101, 1) return "YES"? Or does it return "YES" and "YES" is lost somewhere? I tried inputting a custom input of:

2 1

1 0

And that works just fine. So when n = 1 my method works fine. So why doesn't duel(101, 1) work?

Comment: Q: Have you stepped through the code in your debugger?  Q: Which C++ debugger are you using?

Comment: Fix the compiler warnings first. You function promises to return std::string, but if n > 1 it exits without returning a string.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to use a debugger Paul, I'm new to C++. Thanks a lot S.M.! Your suggestion worked. I just added return duel(s + y, n - 1). I would give you an upvote but I have no idea how to do that. I'm new.

Comment: The function `duel` ends with `if (count == 0) return "NO";`. When `count` is not 0, execution falls off of the end with no return statement. That's not good.